# Mollification in $L^\infty$ norm

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory

I'm looking at mollifiers in $L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)$ spaces and I can't show how $$\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0}\|T_\epsilon-T\|_\infty=0$$ does not hold (here $T_\epsilon$ is the convolution $T*\varphi_\epsilon$ and $\varphi_\epsilon(t)=\frac{1}{\epsilon^n}\varphi\left(\frac{t}{\epsilon}\right)$, with $\varphi$ being the mollifier). Thanks for your help

Comment: Work this out with a simple function $T \in L^\infty$ that is not continuous, e.g. an indicator function of an interval. Then you'll see what happens.

Comment: If $T_\epsilon\to T$ uniformly then $T$ must be continuous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the case $n=1$.  If you take $T = \chi_{[0,1]}$ (the characteristic function of the interval [0,1]) you may verify that
for $\epsilon>0$ small enough $T_{\epsilon}(0)= \frac{1}{2}$ and $T(0)=1$. This idea could be extended to $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: Thanks, I don't know how I couldn't see that